# Mozilla Raindrop installtion problem

Tags: python, raindrop

I am trying to install Mozilla Raindrop on Windows Vista. I have successfully installed Couchdb, Python 2.6 and Mercurial. The command:
hg clone -r 0.1 http://hg.mozilla.org/labs/raindrop
runs successfully.
But when I run check-raindrop.py I get the

> ERROR: The 'setuptools' package is not
>   installed.

Even check-raindrop.py --configure is giving the same error. Can you please guide me so that I can install all dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need Python's setuptools. They are here with [windows installation instructions](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows).

Comment: Thanks jweede. I was able to install all dependencies, but strangle even though I have installed CouchDB 0.10 the version detected by check-raindrop.py is u'0.0.0. Regards